# When is it appropriate to adjust the tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

I just adjusted the tags of one of my recent questions since from reading the answer, I understand now better what I was talking about than before asking.

But now I'm not sure if this was right since it bumpded the question without having added much to it.

More generally when is it appropriate to adjust the tags of a question and when should one better refrain from retagging because it adds no additional value but just bumps the question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the new tagging better characterized the question then it is a good thing.

If we were to see a pattern of re-tagging a lot of question without a clear improvement to the description of then we might ask you to quit bumping, but an honest deeper understanding isn't going to come every day.